# unable to convert dataframe to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Final_data is my dataframe with 3 columns . I am trying to convert it to csv file . Unfortunately it throws error

X1 is a dict and X2 is a list (which i changed to str datatype)

```
final_data.dtypes
Out[191]: 
User ID         int64
X1              object
X2              object
dtype: object


final_data.to_csv(final_data)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       final_data.to_csv(final_data)
>
> File
>   "c:\users\rb287jd\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 1745, in to_csv
>       formatter.save()
>
> File
>   "c:\users\rb287jd\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py",
>   line 162, in save
>       if path_or_buf:
>
> File
>   "c:\users\rb287jd\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
>   line 1573, in **nonzero**
>       .format(self.**class**.**name**))
>
> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Can you add data sample, `print (final_data.head().to_dict())` ?

Comment: Added. Please check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is problem with filename, but all values are converted to strings:

```
final_data.to_csv('filename')
```

---

So if want save nested `list`s with `dict`s better is use `json` by [`to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html):

```
final_data.to_json('filename.json')
```

Or to pickle by [`to_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html):

```
final_data.to_pickle('filename.pkl')
```

Comment: final_data.to_json('filename.json')  this one is working fine. thank you

Answer (score 0):

give the file path and file name inside the parenthesis.

```
final_data.to_csv("\path\new_df.csv")
```